# Improving hadoop Job Performance by multiple Reducers?

Tags: hadoop

I was doing few tests with a MapReduce Jobs Performance.

1. WithOut Combiner -
2. WithCombiner -

I'm convinced and understood that  Using Combiner has improved the Performance of the Jobs.
 Please find the stats of the Jobs in the table. Theoretically, Parallel Processing with Multiple reducers should improve the Job running time, but the stats does not prove that. Could some one answer why the multiple reducers are not improving the job performance.

3. With 1 Reducer
4. With 10 Reducers

### 10 Reducers Performance with Combiner

```
CPU time spent (ms)=27380
Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=1430097920
Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=7202680832
Total committed heap usage (bytes)=502865920
Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=61027
Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=273752
```

### 1 Reducer Performance with Combiner

```
CPU time spent (ms)=17280
Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=491397120
Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1753538560
Total committed heap usage (bytes)=291643392
Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=37374
Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=11416


   Here is the Code : 

   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private Text Words = new Text(); 
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1); 
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable k1, Text v1, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        String line = v1.toString(); 
        String tokens[] = line.split(" ");
        int count = tokens.length;
        int i = 0; 
        while (count >= 1)
        {
            //String a1 = tokens[i];    
            if(tokens[i].contains("172"))
            {
                Words.set(tokens[i]);   
            }
            i++;
            count --; 
            con.write(Words, one);
        }


}}

    import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Iterable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key1, Iterable<IntWritable> values1, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException  
    {
        int sum=0; 

        IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        for (IntWritable val : values1)
        {
        sum = sum + val.get(); 
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key1, result);

    }
}

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;



public class WordCountJob extends Configured implements Tool 

{

    public int  run(String args[]) throws Exception 

    {

        Configuration conf = getConf(); 
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job =  new Job(conf); 
        job.setJarByClass(WordCountJob.class);

        Path in = new Path(args[0]); 
        Path out = new Path(args[1]); 

        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class); 
        //job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.getNumReduceTasks(); 
        job.getCluster(); 
        //job.getStartTime();
        //job.getStatus();



        //Location of the Input  File; Type of the File;
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class); 

        //Location of the Output File; Type of the File 
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out); 
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class) ; 

        //Type of the Data written in Output File. 
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.waitForCompletion(true); 

        return 0 ;
    }


    public static void main(String pars[]) throws Exception 

    {

            int output = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),new WordCountJob(), pars);
            System.exit(output); 
    }



    }
```

Comment: Just by stats we wont be able to commit anything. Where's the code, Did you had any partition? What else has chnaged in between the test? How loaded your environment is? It depends actually.

Comment: @Almas, I have posted the code.
 No Partitioner Set.
 No. of Reducers changed on each Tests. 
  Test 1 ran with 1 Reducer 
  Test 2 Ran with 10 Reducers. 
It is a POC Environment, No load at all. The Job is error count on a webserver log file.

Comment: I see you are doing comparison.. how many output files do you see in HDFS?

Comment: For a Job with 1 Reducer - 1 File.
For a Job with 10 Reduce - 10 Files.

Comment: and 10 reducer still 1 file right?

Comment: You are benchmarking something that takes 11s, the Hadoop overhead is much bigger than that. Do you have bigger data, your sample is too small to draw anything upon?

Comment: @Almas, 10 Reducer ==> 10 files. Not sure if it is possible to get 1 file for 10 Reducers.
Thomas, You're right. I was just experimenting the code on 200MB file. but curious to know the logics and theory, If multiple reducer would improve the job performance (due to parallel Processing).